# Inflating alternate rows for a conversation listview

Tags: android

I am unsure how to get alternating rows inflated for a `listview` with a custom adapter in a sort of conversation style, that is `user1` gets `row_style1` and `user2` gets `row_style2` for their messages respectively. I have the data for both users in the same `JSON object`. I was looking for help as to how best I can get this accomplished. I am not merely trying to get alternating views, but rather for every message user1 sends it always uses `row_style1` and for every message `user2` has `row_style2`. If `user1` sends 3 messages `row_style1` is used for each of those, etc...

```
public class MsgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private ArrayList<String> memName,memAvatar,msgBody,msgTime;
private ArrayList<Integer>  memId;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;



public MsgAdapter(Context context, int resId, ArrayList<String> body, ArrayList<String> avatar, ArrayList<String> name,ArrayList<Integer> memId, ArrayList<String> msgTime, LayoutInflater inflater){
    super(context,resId, body);
    this.msgBody = body;
    this.memName = name;
    this.memAvatar = avatar;
    this.msgTime = msgTime;
    this.memId = memId;
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;

    if(convertView == null){

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_thread_row_sender, parent, false);

    }else
        v = convertView;

    TextView msg         = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.msgBody);
    TextView dateInfo    = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.msgTime);
    ImageView memImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.usrImg);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(memAvatar.get(position), memImg);

    msg.setText(msgBody.get(position));
    dateInfo.setText(msgTime.get(position));

    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 2):

inside your custom adapter you have to override

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

}
```

`getViewTypeCount` has to return the number of different view you want to show (2 in your case), `getItemViewType` should return the type of the view (0 for user1 and 1 for user2 for instance). This way you getView will recive two differents convertView and you can choose how to inflate it, based on the position

Comment: Thanks for the start but I wanted more like all of user 1 messages to be with 1 type of layout and all of user2 messages to be another type of layout

Comment: In `getItemViewType()`, use the position to return a value between 0 and (`getViewTypeCount()` - 1). This is so the ListView knows which recycled View to pass as an argument to your `getView()` method. `getView()` should have the same or similar logic to determine which View type to inflate -- I recommend you simply call `getItemViewType()` from getView and switch on the result.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:
in your get view method

```
View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
//even row
if(position%2==0)
//inflate row_style_1
else
//odd row
//inflate row_style_2
}
```

hope this helps